# Why do I get zero when pushing_back floats to a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

While I was testing someting, I have created a vector of type float, and put the values 1/i into that vector;however, while reading the values, the output is printed as integers and not as float.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::vector<float> testVec;
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        float v = 1/i;
        testVec.push_back(v);
    }

    std::vector< float >::iterator it = testVec.begin();
    for (; it!=testVec.end(); ++it)
    {
        printf("The value of the iterator: %f, *it);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

So, what is the problem with this ? Is it related with the iterator ? I mean I have not much experienced with them.

Comment: `1/i` where `i` is of type integer is **integer arithmetic**.

Comment: `1` is an `int`, `i` is an `int`, so `1/i` is an `int`.

Comment: @AditiRawat Oh, I see. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @AditiRawat I advise you to post your comment as answer.

Comment: So it's not that you "can't puhback" as said in the title, but that you can pushback and are not happy with what you can find back...

Comment: @Christophe That is actually turned out to be the case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind your issue is that `1/i` where `i` is of type integer is **integer arithmetic** and will give integer as output.
`1.0` in place of `1` would help you. :)